# How to make div block fixed as window size changes?

Tags: html, css

Here's my html and css code :

```
<div id="navigation_header">
    .....<br>
    .....<br>
    .....<br>
</div>
<div id="main_page">
    **********
</div>

#navigation_header {
 float:left;   
}
#main_page {
 float:left;   
}
```

As you can see ,the main_page is right to the navigation bar.

However when I resize the browser window , as the width goes smaller , the main_page will appear at the bottom of navigation bar.

How can I make the main page fixed right to navigation bar as I change the window size.

PS: I created a fiddle for this, check it http://jsfiddle.net/E83dH/

Comment: if the size of the window becomes too small to have both elements on the same line.. what would you like to happened? you want the main_page to go on top of the navigation.. or would you like things to resize according the window?

Comment: @EyalBarta I want to remain the origin , and hide the left part of it,which you can scroll to view.

Comment: in that case look at my answer below.. I think it should cover it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you want you should wrap both elements with a DIV and style with a min-width:

```
.wrap { width:100%; min-width:300px;} // * min-width should be the combined width of both elements.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T87q5/

check out the demo

Comment: Definitely! Wise is he who learns from every wo/man :) but in my biased view, I think you ended up choosing the answer that most accurately answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than float your `#main_page`, give it an `overflow` property. It will take up all of and only the available width.

```
#main_page {
    overflow:hidden;  
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/E83dH/2/)

Comment: It seems to change the right part content , splitting one line into  two. Any way to avoid this?

Comment: That's just because of where the space is, if you don't want the element to wrap it's content then you can use `white-space:nowrap;`: http://jsfiddle.net/E83dH/4/

Comment: @JrChen you said this -> 'I want to remain the origin , and hide the left part of it,which you can scroll to view' -- This answer does not do what you described. when becoming a small window, the elements would cut off, not scroll.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide % `width` if you want to change the size of div too according to the screen width.

Here is the css

```
#navigation_header {
 float:left;  
 width:30%;
}
#main_page {
 float:left; 
 width:70%;
}
```

You can check it here [jsfiddle]http://jsfiddle.net/E83dH/1/

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest you do instead is put both things inside a container and give the container a `min width`. Infact give all your div's a `min-width`

http://jsfiddle.net/E83dH/3/

HTML

```
<div class='container'>
    <div id="navigation_header">.....
        <br>.....
        <br>.....
        <br>
    </div>
    <div id="main_page">**********</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#navigation_header {
    float:left;
}
#main_page {
    float:left;
}
.container {
    min-width:300px;
}
```

This will ensure that you get a scrollbar at the bottom but the second div doesn't come below. Note that the `min-width` should be the sum width of the two elements at the point when the second element comes below the first.